# In Webview.. Is it possible when you have no Internet connection it will redirect to another layout?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

Good day, I'm having hard time here. Any help will do.
I have an layout that call xml that has WebView. Is it possible? If I have no internet connection. It will redirect to other layout *Sorry.java* that has text that says. "Sorry you dont have Internet connection this time" ..

This is my codes

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class Translate extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.translate);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());


}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    {
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Add another `TextView` with the error message and `GONE` visibility.
You can then (in the onCreate) check if the internet is online, and if it isn't set the `WebView`'s visibility to `GONE` and set the textview's visiblity to `VISIBLE`, and of course, not try to load the URL in the webview.

**EDIT**
To check if the internet is connected you will need the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission and use this method:

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: how can I check the internet is online?

Comment: Sir my goal is to pass the value to another layout not to create invisible Text. but I appreciate this. it is cool. but my professor   told me to do the layout thing.

Answer (score 0):

This method will check your connectivity:

```
public boolean isDeviceConnectedToInternet() {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager).getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So in your Activity check for connectivity and if no connection is available then go to another Activity:

```
if(!isDeviceConnectedToInternet()) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, OfflineActivity.class));
} else {
    // Show webView
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I got error here.  `NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager).getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();` The ConnectivityManager is the error

Comment: add `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `android.permission.INTERNET` permissions to AndroidManifest.xml